# I am having a difficulty in creating a dataframe in pandas, which is taken from a particular url. Could someone look after this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, html-dataset

```
import pandas as pd
daf = pd.read_html('https://github.com/justmarkham/DAT8/blob/master/data/beer.txt' )
```

*this would extract the dataset from the mentioned url but I am facing trouble in setting up the dataframe with the required index. Just lemme know how to organise the dataset properly. If you dont understand my question, just look at the code and run it and i guess you'll figure out what am i asking. *

Comment: use read_csv or read_fwf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
daf = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/justmarkham/DAT8/blob/master/data/beer.txt', ' ')
```

Comment: You forgot to change read_html to read_csv

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder yeah, you are right, thanks, but someone else already fixed it ! Cool name, by the way !